# Show/Hide multiple divs and toggle parent's background image

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have five divs, each with their own unique background image. Inside each div is a text link. Mousing over any of the divs or text links should create a rollover effect, swapping the div's background. The rollover state for each div is also unique, so div 1 (#colOne) alternates between bgOne.png and bgOne_ro.png, div 2 (#colTwo) between bgTwo.png and bgTwo_ro.png, etc.

That's simple enough to do with CSS, but here's where it gets a little complex.

Clicking on a text link should change its parent div's background to bg*_ro.png so that it persists, even on mouse off. Simultaneously, it should reveal a hidden div, unique to that text link.

This hidden div will have its own close button (presumably via display:hidden with CSS). Closing it should make it so that the parent div of the text link that revealed it should have its background reset back to bg*.png. Things will now behave as they did before revealing the hidden div.

As there are five text links, there are five hidden divs to potentially be revealed. No more than one hidden div should be revealed at any one time. Clicking on a text link should hide whichever hidden div is currently revealed, as well as obviously revealing the div associated with it.

I've included some structural code which hopefully helps make things clearer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color:#333333;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#Container {
width:1000px;
margin:auto;
left:50%;
}
.Column {
width:199px;
height:700px;
float:left;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-color: #FFFFFF;
text-align:center;
}
#colOne {
background-image: url(bgOne.png);
}
#colOne:hover {
background-image: url(bgOne_ro.png);
}
#colTwo {
background-image: url(bgTwo.png);
}
#colTwo:hover {
background-image: url(bgTwo_ro.png);
}
#colThree {
background-image: url(bgThree.png);
}
#colThree:hover {
background-image: url(bgThree_ro.png);
}
#colFour {
background-image: url(bgFour.png);
}
#colFour:hover {
background-image: url(bgFour_ro.png);
}
#colFive {
background-image: url(bgFive.png);
}
#colFive:hover {
background-image: url(bgFive_ro.png);
}
a {
position:relative;
text-align:center;
top:600px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Container">
  <div class="Column" id="colOne">
    <a>Testing</a>
</div>
  <div class="Column" id="colTwo">
    <a>Testing</a>
</div>
  <div class="Column" id="colThree">
    <a>Testing</a>
</div>
  <div class="Column" id="colFour">
    <a>Testing</a>
</div>
  <div class="Column" id="colFive">
    <a>Testing</a>    
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.Column').click(function () {
  $('#Container').css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Marian. It's actually the #colOne backgrounds that need to have the rollover effect. #Container is simply a container to position the divs in the center.